# Is the BIVS still in effect during COVID times?

Tags: uk, covid-19, ireland

In the course of the Covid pandemic the Irish [Short Stay Visa Waiver Programme has been suspended](http://www.inis.gov.ie/en/INIS/Pages/PR20000007) for an effectively indefinite amount of time. While pages on the [SSVWP](http://www.inis.gov.ie/en/INIS/Pages/Irish%20Short%20Stay%20Visa%20Waiver%20Programme) show a warning that it is on hold, [BIVS](http://www.inis.gov.ie/en/INIS/Pages/British%20Irish%20Visa%20Scheme) explanations only state that

> The British Irish Visa Scheme will build on Ireland’s Short-stay Visa Waiver Programme

but provide no further info on whether it is also suspended due to suspension of the SSVWP.

While I would assume that to be the case, is there any more definitive/legally binding source that can confirm or refute this assumption?

Comment: note: I'd also be greatful for links or other references to sources I could look up/contact in order to obtain this information

Comment: The SSVWP and the BIVS are different schemes. The suspension of one does not necessarily affect the other. The reference that you quote suggesting that one builds on the other is meant in an economic sense (i.e. more visitors) only.

Comment: @Arthur'sPass is that evidenced by the fact that the documents constituting the rules of each do not directly reference the other in any way, or how could the claim that they are different and practically independent of each other be proven? (If you know, might you want to post that as an answer over on my question on [Law](https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/56647/are-the-irish-short-stay-visa-waiver-programme-and-british-irish-visa-scheme-dir)?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to a mail response from the [Department of Justice and Equality](http://www.inis.gov.ie/en/INIS/Pages/Home) (as of September 25th):

> It is currently still possible to travel to Ireland using the British Irish
> Visa Scheme, please see information on the operation of this scheme at the
> [following link](http://www.inis.gov.ie/en/INIS/Pages/British+Irish+Visa+Scheme)